# NPOI CloneStyleFrom not working as expected

Tags: c#, npoi

CloneStyleFrom does not work as I would expect it to.

I would expect `cellStyleBorderThin.CloneStyleFrom(cellStyleBorderThick);` to clone settings and not alter the original style.  After altering the *cellStyleBorderThin* settings, *cellStyleBorderThick* now contains the same border settings.

I checked each cellStyleBorder index.  Each one has a unique id.

I would expect columns B, D and F to have a thick border.

[image]

Code sample below.

```
// read the workbook
IWorkbook wb;
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(newPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
}

var cellStyleBorderThick = GetDefaultStyle(wb);

var cellStyleBorderThin = wb.CreateCellStyle();
cellStyleBorderThin.CloneStyleFrom(cellStyleBorderThick);
cellStyleBorderThin.BorderRight = BorderStyle.Thin;
cellStyleBorderThin.BorderBottom = BorderStyle.Thin;
cellStyleBorderThin.BorderLeft = BorderStyle.Thin;
cellStyleBorderThin.BorderTop = BorderStyle.Thin;
// Adding this font did not impact cellStyleBorderThick.  Curious.  Only borders seem to be impacted.
cellStyleBorderThin.SetFont(GetFont(wb, 20));

// helper function to create font
private static XSSFFont GetFont(IWorkbook wb, double size)
{
var font = (XSSFFont)wb.CreateFont();
font.FontHeightInPoints = size;
font.FontName = "Calibri";

return font;
}

// helper function to get default style
private static ICellStyle GetDefaultStyle(IWorkbook wb)
{

var cellStyleBorderThick = wb.CreateCellStyle();
cellStyleBorderThick.SetFont(GetFont(wb, 10));
cellStyleBorderThick.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
cellStyleBorderThick.BorderRight = BorderStyle.Thick;
cellStyleBorderThick.BorderBottom = BorderStyle.Thick;
cellStyleBorderThick.BorderLeft = BorderStyle.Thick;
cellStyleBorderThick.BorderTop = BorderStyle.Thick;
cellStyleBorderThick.Alignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;

return cellStyleBorderThick;
}
```

**NPOI v2.5.1**

Comment: I have the same problem, but in my case the style that gets the borders wrong is a second cloned style, not the base style I use to configure both cloned styles.

Comment: After some research I found that this is a known bug in v2.5.1.

https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi/issues/288